# How do I implement a second non-unique identifier without concurrency issues?

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dbal

Given this MySQL table `references` where `uid` is the primary and unique key:

```
uid |reference_id | foreign_id
1   | 1           | 123  
2   | 1           | 234
3   | 2           | 345
4   | 2           | 456
5   | 2           | 567
```

My plan is to use the `reference_id` as a sort of non unique identifier which identifies a group of references. I also want to increment it every time a new group is inserted.
Since this field is nor unique or auto incremented for new inserts I have to check for the last used `reference_id`, increment that and insert with the newfound id. This can of course have a big concurrency issue when inserts calculate the next `reference_id` at the same time.

Does anyone have any leads on how to solve this problem? I thought about table locking but I'm not sure if this is feasible given my DB engine agnostic Doctrine/DBAL which I am using.

Comment: I would suggest not going this route.  Instead, consider using a timestamp as a unique identifier for each incoming batch of N records.  Or, you could use a UUID for each batch.  If you need to _view_ your table with the above `reference_id` sequence, then use `DENSE_RANK` ordered by that timestamp or UUID.

Comment: Well Tim a timestamp would not eliminate the problem of concurrency, UUIDs might but they're probably not as easy to index and not very good performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

This information should be in another table, with an auto increment key.  Something like this:

```
create table batches (
    batch_id int auto_increment primary key,
    dt datetime
    . . .   -- other information, such as the creation date
);
```

Then your inserts would look like:

```
insert into batches (datetime)
    values (now());

set @id = last_insert_id();

insert to references (uid, batch_id, foreign_id)
    values (?, @id, ?), . . .;
```